# Renaming file with parent and grandparent directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, filenames

If there is a file path like:

```
/path/topic/day/name.pdf
```

Is there a way in bash to rename the file include the name of the parent and grandparent directory that the file is in?

eg.

```
/path/topic/day/topic-day.pdf
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

function assemble_path() {
  echo "$(realpath "$1" | rev | cut -d'/' -f2- | rev)"
}

function assemble_parents() {
  echo "$(echo "$1" | rev | cut -d"/" -f-2 | rev | tr '/' '-')"
}

function rename_to_parents() {
  filetype=$(echo "$1" | rev | cut -d"." -f1 | rev)
  filepath=$(assemble_path "$1")
  parents=$(assemble_parents "$filepath")
  mv "$(realpath "$1")" "$filepath/$parents.$filetype"
}
rename_to_parents "$1"
```

---

Usage:

1. save this script in a file e.g. `rename.sh`
2. add execution privileges to it e.g. `chmod u+x rename.sh`
3. execute it with a file as argument, that you want to rename e.g. `./rename.sh name.pdf`

Output (for `/path/topic/day/name.pdf`):

```
/path/topic/day/topic-day.pdf
```